# PHP session timeout occurs early even though a higher value is set

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, timeout

I have added the following lines in my htaccess file :

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 14400
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 14400
```

Also have added a php.ini file in the root directory with the following code :

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 14400
session.cookie_lifetime = 14400
```

Also inside the php code have added the following lines :

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',14400);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',14400);
setcookie("_lid", $lid, time() + 14400);
```

So basically the session should work for 4 hours. But it is getting timed out in about 24 mins or so which is the default timeout time in php.

I may be missing something. Would be great if someone can provide some inputs.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot yet answer your question in whole, but a php.ini in your web root has no use. php does not use it. it will only use the one in your main configuration folder.

Comment: Just curious, why would you set the session lifetime if you only want to set a non-related cookie? What are you trying to accomplish? You can always set a cookie with a greater retention time, no matter what the session time is.

Comment: To check the login authorization a session variable is used which is checked and that gets removed after some time even though the cookie is retained.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the exact same issue.  And I check via phpinfo() and the session.gc_maxlifetime & session.cookie_lifetime are both set to 14400 - It is clearly a) not working as designed or b) using something else to determine session timeout...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem - the session.gc_maxlifetime & session.cookie_lifetime values were set but appeared to not be honoured... Then, I found a comment on an old thread which clearly needs a lot more recognition:

[How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

> Please note that at least two settings are crucial to setting the
>   session time, and maybe three. The two certainly crucial ones are
>   session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime (where 0 is not the
>   same as some long number). For complete, 100% certainty of allowing
>   long times, it may also be necessary to set the session.save_path, due
>   to varying OS-controled cleanup time on the /tmp directory where
>   session files get stored by default. – @Kzqai Apr 7 '11 at 8:04